# Proper pattern for nested asks

Tags: c#, akka.net

I have an actor with many children and I am querying it to get an aggregate of the data in its children. This operation could take a few seconds.

I was about to do this and it feels so completely wrong. The handle method is called by an `Ask<>`.

```
public void Handle(Message message)
{
    var children = Context.GetChildren();
    var tasks = new List<Task<Result>>();

    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        var t = child.Ask<Result>(new Query);
        tasks.Add(t);
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray()); // Gah!
    // do some work
    Sender.Tell(new Response(new Results()));
}
```

I have a few ideas, but wanted to get some input as I don't really want to reinvent a 20 sided wheel.

I am worried about the reference to `Sender` and what it will be pointing at when I finally get to call `Tell` on it as it is a static call.

I've ended up using the `Task.WhenAll` continuation, but still not convinced it's the right Akka way - which is the point here. I can make it work, I just want to know the best practice options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general `Ask` should be used only for the communication with an actor from external services, almost never between two actors. It's a lot more expensive than using `Tell`. Additional problem is to use `Task.WaitAll` which actually blocks current thread until all responses will arrive, which is also bad for performance and may end up with deadlock.

Similar [thread](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/1292) was already discussed on github.

General solution for aggregation problems is:

- Create a separate actor for aggregation process.
- Initialize it with list of actors, it is supposed to collect data from and remember the actor, which will be informed with collected result.
- Send request/query for each actor.
- Handle each request/query response, aggregating it in separate data structure and remove a sender from the list of awaited actors.
- Once there is no actor to await for - send a result and stop current actor (the one responsible for data aggregation).
- Attach `ReceiveTimeout` mechanism in case, when for some reason not all actors are able to respond in reasonable time - when timeout will hit, you may return failure or list of responses collected so far.

PS: Don't use TypedActor - it's also bad for performance and is/will become obsoleted.

Comment: Cool thanks. The ask thing surprises me. So you are saying that an ask is more expensive than a tell that responds with a tell to sender? Yeah the WaitAll is what made my eyes bleed. Great link, thought it wasn't what i wanted then became a little piece of awesome.

Comment: The reason that Ask is expensive is that it both creates a Task and a temporary actor that will receive the response from the Asked actor. the temp actor is also registered under `/temp`, registering and unregistering is also somewhat expensive.

Comment: Will the memory of the temporary actors be automatically released by AKKA.NET. Just if too many requests will  cause memory leaks

Comment: @sam1977 akka by itself won't collect idle actors. You can do it easily with setting `ReceiveTimeout` - which will trigger if actor will be idle for some time - and explicitly call `Context.Stop(Self)` if actor is no longer necessary.

Comment: Thanks @ Horusiath