# How can a parent actor track status of a sub tasks performed by child actors

Tags: c#, akka, akka.net

I have an actor system that parses a large data, the way I implemented is the parent actor divide the task to multiple child actors that run in parallel. This part works fine. My question is how can the parent actor get the status of each child so that it knows the sub tasks are completed?

Comment: Why not simply have the child actors message their parent when they complete their work using `Context.Parent.Tell()`? Doesn't sound like you need anything more complicated than that.

Comment: well that is what i am doing . when the parent receives a message ImportCustomerData , it dispatches 4 child actors ImportData, the parent then waits for ImportComplet message from all 4 child actors then the task is complete. the way i am doing it now is the parent maintains list dictionary of CustomerId and flag for the for data items being processed by child actors.   i was asking if there was a better way.

Comment: I think you're on the right track. See also [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32433259/1138552) (and the link in that post) which covers a question very similar to what you want to do, which is basically the "aggregator pattern". If you google for "aggregator pattern" you'll find more material you may find useful! :)

Comment: @easuter I was just about to answer with the aggregator pattern here before I saw your comment.  Should really be an answer I think, it's the correct thing to do.

Comment: @PatrickAllwood yeah, I should probably have put that comment in an answer, will do, thanks :)

Comment: @easuter Looks like my approach was close enough , although the link you shared  creating a an actor for aggregating result is much more cleaner .

Answer (score -1):

Make the child actors tell the parent actor when they are finished, they could also tell updates etc.

Edit: If you want the results of an aggregate of responses ... then use an actor to aggregate the responses? Alternatively just use a count. However the answer is perfectly valid and correct if you apply even 20 seconds of thought. If you want a child actor to provide update its parent of its progress - no matter the complexity of the solution - you have to tell the parent its progress. If you want to insert actors into the middle or use a count in the parent actor to figure out how far through the complete process you are the answer is STILL tell the parent upon completion.

You will get answers to what you ask. If you ask the wrong question then just because the answers don't answer the question you wanted doesn't mean they are wrong (especially given they are still the right answer)

People answering questions on here are not required - nor should be expected - to read the comments on a question - the asker is however required to update the question. Not being funny, but i am fairly busy and you shouldn't be making me work to help you.

This question should be closed as its a duplicate /  vague / incorrect.
When you get responses like this to legitimately answering questions it makes the aggression of SO answerers towards askers feel justified.

Comment: if you see my my comment up there, just sending message to parent does not solve my problem , i was mostly concerned with how to better aggregate the results of child actor to determine whether the task as whole is complete or not.

Comment: @John Nicholas, you're right and I don't know why you were downvoted. I also tried adding an answer based on my comments on the OP and immediately got 2 downvotes with a moderator/reviewer chastising me for providing a link to another answer - here on SO - that satisfies the question. Apparently I'm to copy over someone else's answer here or maybe implement the solution myself?...SO is going downhill with crap like this. (edit: I don't think it was OP doing the downvoting as he takes some time between replies).

Comment: @easuter crazy isn't it. I think the moral is don't go near or post questions with a c# tag  ... If its a dupe question then imo linking to another question is entirely appropriate especially if you do not have flag privileges. I kind of stopped helping people on here. Amusing observation - the linked question is one i asked.

Comment: @JohnNicholas i want to accept your edited version as an answer but you have unnecessary lecturing that is not relevant to to the question frankly belongs to on FAQ/how to page of stackoverflow , you sounded bitter there , not sure what i did wrong.

Comment: well i am bitter whenever i try and answer something on here. Its not you its the community. I spent most of my time on here trying to reopen and edit questions so they can get useful answers. When you do answer you get downvoted with no explanations. If i helped you im happy, thats all that matters.